# Check Type of Object ios swift

Tags: xcode, swift

How do I check the type of object my variable is in ios swift?

For Example

```
let test= ["Chicago", "New York", "Oregon", "Tampa"]
```

is test NSArray? NSMutableArray? NSString?

I'm used to visual studio using an immediate window, can this be in debug mode in Xcode?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093433/how-to-determine-the-type-of-a-variable-in-swift

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several methods for determine an object's type at debug or compile time.

---

If the variable's type is explicitly declared, just look for it:

```
let test: [String] = ["Chicago", "New York", "Oregon", "Tampa"]
```

Here, `test` is clearly marked as a `[String]` (a Swift array of `String`s).

---

If the variable's type is implicitly inferred, we can get some information by <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+clicking.

```
let test = ["Chicago", "New York", "Oregon", "Tampa"]
```

[image]

Here, we can see `test`'s type is `[String]`.

---

We can print the object's type using `dynamicType`:

```
let test = ["Chicago", "New York", "Oregon", "Tampa"]

println(test.dynamicType)
```

Prints:

```
Swift.Array<Swift.String>
```

---

We can also see our variable in the variable's view:

[image]

Here, we can see the variable's type clearly in the parenthesis: [String]

---

Also, at a break point, we can ask the debugger about the variable:

```
(lldb) po test
["Chicago", "New York", "Oregon", "Tampa"]

(lldb) po test.dynamicType
Swift.Array<Swift.String>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `is` in Swift.

```
if test is NSArray {
  println("is NSArray")
}
```

Comment: problem is i dont know the variable type and would like to avoid inserting multiple if statements .  Can I just check the variable type while I step through the code in debug mode?  if so, is there an immediate window in xcode?

Comment: @DevTonio In xCode console, you can printout the values for variables by `po test`. It will print the information about the object there.

Answer (score 1):

```
type(of:)
```

Which Returns the dynamic type of a value.

```
func foo<T>(x: T) -> T.Type {
  return type(of: x)
}
```