# SwiftyJSON - is possible to check object type?

Tags: ios, swifty-json

For example I have a json

`var json = JSON(data: data!)`

inside it I reference to object

`var list = json["OBJECT"]`

is there a way, that I can check if it is an object, or array, or string and return bool ?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093433) doesnt help. `var list` will always be type of `JSON`. And I want to find a way to check what is inside.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine the type of a variable in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093433/how-to-determine-the-type-of-a-variable-in-swift)

Comment: Explained why it is not duplicate.

Comment: Most JSON strings received over the network are distinct – at least the collection types they return – so you should "know" rather than "guess".

Comment: you did have time to comment and edit. i suggest you take a second to pick an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The JSON objects in SwiftyJSON have a `type` property whose type is an `enum`

```
public enum Type: Int {
    case number
    case string
    case bool
    case array
    case dictionary
    case null
    case unknown
}
```

For example

```
var list = json["OBJECT"]
switch list.type {
  case .array: print("list is Array")
  case .dictionary: print("list is Dictionary")
  default: break
}
```

Comment: when I try this I get... Pattern cannot match values of type 'Type' errors on both case lines

Comment: @SamLuther In Swift 3+ the enum cases are lowercased. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

look at this example:

```
//let json = ["OBJECT":"stringvalue"]

let testArray = [1,2,3]
let json = ["OBJECT":testArray]

if let element = json["OBJECT"] {
    if element is String {
        print("yes")
    }
    switch element {
    case is String:
        print("is string")
    case is Array<Int>:
        print("is array of int")
    default:
        print("is something else")
    }
}
```