# Can I group two functions with Generics into one function in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have two bellow functions with Generics.

```
func objectFunc<T:SomeProtocol>(obj:T)
func arrayFunc<T:SomeProtocol>(obj:[T])
```

Can I group these functions into one function?

I found the link [Checking if an object is a given type in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24091892/2520998), but this is a little different.

---

Added.

For example, I want to do like bellow.

```
func objectAndArrayFunc<T>(arg:T, someEnum:SomeEnum){
  switch someEnum {
    case A:
      // something
    case B:
      // something
  }

  if let items = arg as? [T] {
    for item in items {
      // something
    }
  } else if let item = arg as? T {
      // something
  }
  // I want to do something [T] and T common processing

}
enum SomeEnum {
  case A
  case B
}
```

Also, SomeEnum count might increase.

Comment: what result do you expect? If you need to merge functions on compile-time.
You can group this functions into one in struct, for example.

Comment: You mean overloading them?

Comment: thanks, comment.
I added example above question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, depends on what `// something` is. There are many ways ...

**Private common processor**

```
protocol Property {
  var name: String{ get }
}

enum SomeEnum {
  case A, B
}

func process<T:Property>(object:T, someEnum:SomeEnum) {
  process(object, nil, someEnum)
}

func process<T:Property>(objects:[T], someEnum:SomeEnum) {
  process(nil, objects, someEnum)
}

private func process<T:Property>(object: T?, objects:[T]?, someEnum:SomeEnum) {
  switch someEnum {
    case .A:
      // something
      break
    case .B:
      // something
      break
  }

  // holds all items for common processing
  var itemsToProcess: [T] = []

  if let items = objects {
    // process items
    itemsToProcess = items
    for item in items {
      println("\(item.name)")
    }
  } else if let item = object {
    // process single item
    itemsToProcess = [item]
    println("\(item.name)")
  }

  // iterate over single/all items and process them
  for item in itemsToProcess {
    println("\(item.name)")
  }
}
```

**Wrap it to Enum**

```
protocol Property {
  var name: String{ get }
}

enum SomeEnum {
  case A, B
}

enum Objects<T> {
  case Single(T)
  case Multiple([T])
}

private func process<T:Property>(objects: Objects<T>, someEnum:SomeEnum) {
  switch someEnum {
    case .A:
      // something
      break
    case .B:
      // something
      break
  }

  // holds all items for common processing
  var itemsToProcess: [T] = []

  switch objects {
    case .Multiple(let items):
      // process items
      itemsToProcess = items
      for item in items {
        println("\(item.name)")
    }

    case .Single(let item):
      // process single item
      itemsToProcess = [item]
      println("\(item.name)")
  }

  // iterate over single/all items and process them
  for item in itemsToProcess {
    println("\(item.name)")
  }
}

struct Prop: Property {
  var name: String {
    return "hi"
  }
}

let prop = Prop()
process(.Single(prop), .A)
process(.Multiple([prop]), .B)
```

Unfortunately, the 2nd example segfaults Swift 1.2 compiler.

Anyway, it really depends on what your goal is. Why you do not want pass even single item as `[T]`, ...

To answer your question - no, you can't pass `T` or `[T]` in one argument, different types. Unless you wrap it to `Enum` or whatever, unless you do want to use `AnyObject` and make `as` dances, ...