# How to check/cast class to generic type with where in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, casting

I came with with this simple playground illustrating my problem:

```
import UIKit

protocol MyProtocol {
    var foo: Bool { get set }
}

class MyGenericClass<T: UIView where T: MyProtocol>: UIView {}

func checkIfIsMyGenericClass(view: UIView) -> Bool {
    return view is MyGenericClass // Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
}
```

**I need help to identify instances of `MyGenericClass`.**

My actual code isn't that simple, please don't ask me to change `MyGenericClass` declaration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if an object is a given type in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091882/checking-if-an-object-is-a-given-type-in-swift)

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Can you not check against a particular T?

Comment: @jtbandes I can't because I wanna check against any `T` that extends `UIView` and conforms to `MyProtocol`

Answer (score 0):

MyGenericClass has an associatedType requirements. I am not sure but could you try something like

```
import UIKit

protocol MyProtocol {
    var foo: Bool { get set }
}

class MyGenericClass<T: UIView where T: MyProtocol>: UIView {}

func checkIfIsMyGenericClass<T: UIView where T: MyProtocol>(view: T) -> Bool {
    return view is MyGenericClass<T> // Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
}
```

**UPDATED**

```
import UIKit

protocol MyProtocol {
    var foo: Bool { get set }
}

class View: UIView, MyProtocol {
    var foo: Bool = true
}

class MyGenericClass<T: UIView where T: MyProtocol>: UIView {

    var variable: T!

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
    }

}

let view = View()
let obj = MyGenericClass<View>()
obj.variable = view
let anyOtherObj = UIView()


func checkIfIsMyGenericClass<T: UIView where T: MyProtocol>(view: UIView, type: T) -> Bool {
    return view is MyGenericClass<T>
}

checkIfIsMyGenericClass(obj, type: view) // returns true
checkIfIsMyGenericClass(anyOtherObj, type: view) // returns false
```

Comment: I can't because my parameter `view` isn't the one that extends `UIView` and implements `MyProtocol`, but it is an instance of `MyGenericClass` that has that generic type