# How to get the object type in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift

The code is as follows, in the OC to get the object type using [touch.view class], in Swift 3 how to get it.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

if ([NSStringFromClass([touch.view class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellContentView"]) {
    return NO;
} else {
    return YES;
}
}
```

Comment: type(of: yourObject) use this

Comment: In this case you would use `is` or `as?` as in these answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/26384597/1187415, http://stackoverflow.com/a/30304590/1187415 to the duplicate.

Comment: You shouldn't have been using Strings to compare classes like this, in the first place. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40388434/3141234

Comment: Everybody is way overcomplicating this. All you need is `return !(touch.view is UITableViewCellContentView)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on @jglasse's answer, you can get the type of an object by using

```
let theType = type(of: someObject)
```

You can then get a string from that by

```
let typeString = String(describing: type)
```

Or in one line:

```
let typeString = String(describing: type(of: someObject))
```

Comment: in swift 4  i got warning: **Variable used within its own initial value** plz help

Comment: Just use a different name for the variable than "type". Swift 4 has probably changed the name resolution mechanism.

Comment: If you call it objectType or something it should work.

Comment: thanks you it's work **:D**

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3, to determine type of your object, you can use:

```
type(of: yourObject)
```

Example:

```
let myString = "I'm a String!"

let myType = type(of: myString)

print(myType) // prints "String\n"
```