# Swift 3: How to *specify* class of object, ruling out parent memberships?

Tags: ios, swift3

I have seen various answers to similar questions here, but this is different (in particular, this very extensive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388337/swift-3-how-to-verify-class-type-of-object) did not help.

Let me explain: If you are inside the scope of a parent class, how can you - in just one line of code - rule out that an object is an instance of precisely this class but NOT an instance of any of that classes' child's class?

Code example:

```
class Subchild: Child {
     //blabla
}

class Child: Parent {
     //blabla
}

class Parent {
    //....could be NSObject or generic Swift class
    func iAmNotARealParent() -> Bool {
        enter code here
    }    
}
```

... so that I can do:

```
let myObject:Subchild = ...
myObject.iAmNotARealParent()   //<--- returns true

let anotherObject:Child = ...
anotherObject.iAmNotARealParent() //<---- returns true

let thirdObject:Parent = ...
thirdObject.iAmNotARealParent() //<---- returns false
```

In my particular case I am dealing with trying to identify inside UIViews whether "self" is an actual UIView, or any of its many subclasses (UIButton, etc).
I do **not** want to have to check it like this:

```
if self is UIBUtton {return false}
if self is UIScrollView {return false}
```

etc., because then I have to exclude explicitly all child classes.

How do I do this? Is there a *exactClassOf / exactTypeOf * function in Swift I missed? Note I am looking for a solution for both Swift-derived and NSObject derived classes (i.e. for *Any*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
if type(of: self) == Parent.self {
    // this only runs for exact type matches, not subclasses
}
```

That checks for equality of the *types* rather than polymorphic conformance of the instance (i.e. `self is Parent`)

Comment: Aah -- elegant! Thanks!