# Check "isKind(of: )" from list of array with classes

Tags: arrays, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have an array of viewController class names like (ViewController class 1, 2 ,3 4)

```
 let classArray = [VCclass1, VCclass2, VCclass3, VCclass4]
```

I want to check the object belongs to any of the class mentioned in class array like

```
if obj.isKind(of:(Any of the classArray elements) ) {

 //do something

 } else {

//execute else condition

}
```

How can I write "if condition" here?

Comment: If obj was a number, and the array was `[1, 2, 3]`, how would you check?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're looking to see if your array contains a member according to the type of `obj`. So, `contains(where:)` is a perfect fit:

```
if classes.contains(where: { type(of: obj) == $0 }) {
    //do something
} else {
    //execute else condition
}
```

Comment: yes, this is a much cleaner way than my answer. very nice...not to mention it also supports non-NSObject classes.

Comment: @Jake Whenever you write a for loop like yours, just consider: "Can I use `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, `contains(where:)`, or `index(where:)`?". More often than not, you can

Comment: the question is not about searching in the array, the question is about how to find the obj is kind of any of the classes in array. @Shial solution would works best I guess

Comment: @MaryamFekri Apart from him using the ObjC API (`isKind(of:)`) and me using the Swift variant (`is`), our answers are the same ...

Comment: you code doesn't work for me! I have array of UIView.Type but it says $0 expected to be Type

Comment: oops, should be `type(of: obj) == $0` https://repl.it/repls/ComfortableCloudyShockwave

Answer (score 2):

You can verify that in a simple way.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class A: UIViewController {}
class B: UIViewController {}
class C: UIViewController {}

let array:[UIViewController.Type] = [A.self,B.self,C.self]
let obj = A()

print(array.contains(where: { obj.isKind(of: $0) }))
```

Output should be `true`. You can run this code in Playground
However I would recommend `switch` for that purpose. In more complicated scenario you will want to know which class is given object or so.

```
switch obj {
case is A:
    print("A")
case is B:
    print("B")
case is C:
    print("C")
default:
    print("none")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
extension NSObject {
    func isKind(of classes: [AnyClass]) -> Bool {
        for aClass in classes {
            if self.isKind(of: aClass) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}

let classes = [UIViewController.self]
let obj = UIViewController()

if (obj.isKind(of: classes)) {
    //do something
}
```

or the uglier, less OOP way...

```
var isKindOfClass = false
for aClass in classes {
    if obj.isKind(of: aClass) {
        isKindOfClass = true
        break
    }
}

if isKindOfClass {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but there's no need to reinvent the wheel. Just use `contains`. Furthermore, don't use `isKind(of:)` in Swift. Just use `is`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40388434/3141234