# Matching data type in Swift

Tags: swift, expression

I'm using BeaconKit to detect near beacons around.

I want to check if the beacon detected is of type `AltBeacon`. My code is showing an error because of the matching expression I'm using.

```
if beacon.beaconType == AltBeacon {
     print("Detected an AltBeacon")
}
```

Here is the error message I'm getting

> Binary operator `==` cannot be applied to operands of type `Int`' and `AltBeacon.Type`

What can I use instead so I can correct my matching expression please ! Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if an object is a given type in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091882/checking-if-an-object-is-a-given-type-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```swift
if beacon.beaconType is AltBeacon {
   print("Detected an AltBeacon")
}
```

or instead, you can check

```swift
if let beacon.beaconType as? AltBeacon {
   print("Detected an AltBeacon")
} else {
// handle
}
```

Comment: Actually according to the source code both `if` expressions will always evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear. `beaconType` is an `Int`. It cannot be compared with anything else but an `Int`

Two possible solutions:

1. Figure out the integer value of `AltBeacon` (2 is just an example) and compare

   ```
   if beacon.beaconType == 2 { ...
   ```
2. As `AltBeacon` is a subclass of `Beacon` check the type of the *instance*

   ```
   if beacon is AltBeacon { ...
   ```